# Looking for material on how to 'use' Rashi in the gemara

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, rashi, rishonim

Where can I find material like 'klalei Rashi'? 
I'm looking for things such as what Rashi means when he uses certain words and things like that.

Comment: check the back of berachos

Comment: try Yad Malachi

Comment: You mean like, for example, when he says kelomar, he means there was another interpretation of the gemara he's negating?

Comment: [Darchei Hatalmud](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21689&st=&pgnum=54&hilite=) see also this very related Q: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7386/do-any-rishonim-discuss-how-to-approach-rashis-commentary-on-gemara/38371#38371