# What is the Hebrew pasuk for "your body is a temple"

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, health-safety-shmira

What is the Hebrew pasuk for "your body is a temple"/your body is G-D's resting and is holy it needs to be nourished, etc.?

I am not sure exactly what the phrase is in English but I know its something along those lines what is the actual pasuk in Hebrew though?

I am not looking for the Hebrew translation but rather how its actully written in the Torah which is obviuosly very different from modern Hebrew.

Comment: yaakov, [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! I think this question is clear enough to be answerable, but would you please consider [edit]ing it to improve the capitalization, punctuation, etc., to make it a bit more readable? I hope you'll look around and find other information of interest, perhaps starting with some of our [tag:health-safety-shmira] questions.

Comment: Can you tell us where you saw it? I don't think this is in the bible...

Comment: How do you know this is a hebrew pasuk that you ask about it? Where did you hear about it? Telling us info like that can help someone locate it.

Comment: maybe referring to tzelm Elokim

Comment: וַיִּבְרָ֨א אֱלֹהִ֤ים ׀ אֶת־הָֽאָדָם֙ בְּצַלְמ֔וֹ בְּצֶ֥לֶם אֱלֹהִ֖ים בָּרָ֣א אֹת֑וֹ זָכָ֥ר וּנְקֵבָ֖ה בָּרָ֥א אֹתָֽם

Comment: To close voters: I don't think that this question is off-topic, even if the answer might be in the New Testament. It might be unclear, as the original poster did not tell us where he heard that this idea was represented in the Jewish Torah, but that does not make this off-topic, either.

Comment: okay i got it someone answered thank you so much וְעָ֥שׂוּ לִ֖י מִקְדָּ֑שׁ וְשָׁכַנְתִּ֖י בְּתוֹכָֽם is what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the likely source of the saying you're interested in is actually in the [Christian Bible](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/1-Corinthians-6-19/). (Hat-tip: [paquda](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1807/paquda)) As such, there would not be an original Biblical Hebrew version of it.

---

If you want something from the Torah that goes in that direction, consider Exocus 25:8 (Hat-tip: [kouty](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/9215/kouty)):

> וְעָ֥שׂוּ לִ֖י מִקְדָּ֑שׁ וְשָׁכַנְתִּ֖י בְּתוֹכָֽם׃
>
> And let them make Me a sanctuary that I may dwell among them.

This verse relates the building of the Temple to God's "dwelling" among the Jews. There are [various opinions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/make-a-mikdash-but-we-are-making-a-mishkan) as to what that actually means.

Comment: Note that dwelling among Jews is very different from their bodies being temples, which world be dwelling inside of Jews. The latter is certainly a homiletical interpretation. Note that no opinions in the liked page even mention it. This is somewhat misleading.

Comment: thank you וְעָ֥שׂוּ לִ֖י מִקְדָּ֑שׁ וְשָׁכַנְתִּ֖י בְּתוֹכָֽם is what i was looking for